# detect components in order to instal the right drivers

Tags: windows-xp, drivers

I just installed windows xp to machine of one of my friends. Now i need to install the right drivers. In device manager doesn't seems to be any problem but i need to install the right drivers to boost components performance

Any idea?

Comment: if at all possible always get your drivers from the source.
starting with the motherboard chipset from the MB manufacture.
even if you gotta open up the case and take a look inside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, [DeviceDoctor](http://www.devicedoctor.com/) detects all your hardware, checks the current versions of the drivers and lets you know if there's an updated version. You can download and install them individually.

Answer (score 0):

http://devid.info and http://www.pcidatabase.com/ can also be helpful. I didn't try the device doctor, but many other utilities I've seen looked like malware, so I resorted to using the websites only without any tools to find the device names, and then googled the official websites.